# Nivo slider doesn't works fine with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

i just wondering with one error that like

Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; BTRS100200; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; InfoPath.3; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Thu, 20 Mar 2014 12:43:24 UTC


Message: Invalid procedure call or argument
Line: 20
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:2055/EasyWeb/js/jquery.js
```

how ever this works fine with other browsers.

when my Nivo slider scrolls.

here is call code :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: We can't see your nivo-slider-call code.

Comment: @czachor - ya i updated my question.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @j08691- ya it's jQuery v1.9.0